# How to extract individual ips of ec2 instances launch using ansible when count is more than 1

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am launching aws ec2 2 instances using ansible using count:2 please check below playbook

```
- name: Create an EC2 instance
  ec2:
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ key }}"
    key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    group: "{{ security_group }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    wait: yes
    count: 2
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ vpc_subnet_id }}"
    assign_public_ip: "{{ assign_public_ip }}"
  register: ec2

- name: Add the newly created 1 EC2 instance(s) to webserver group
  lineinfile: dest=inventory
              insertafter='^\[webserver\]$'
              line="{{ item.private_ip }} {{hoststring}}"
              state=present
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

- name: add newly created remaining ec2 instance to db group
  lineinfile: dest=inventory
              insertafter='^\[db-server\]$'
              line="{{ item.private_ip }} {{hoststring}}"
              state=present
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

Here i want to add one ip to webserver host group & remaining to db host group but its not working with above playbook please help me to achieve same?

i dont wnt to use add_host here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using AWS, have you considered using the [aws_ec2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.html) plugin for dynamic inventory?

As long as you are tagging your instances correctly, and you set up the yaml file, it would do what you want it.

Otherwise, your `register: ec2` has two elements in it. The way (if it worked) you are looping through `ec2` would add both to each group. You would need to add a `when` condition to match the something like the tag/subnet/cidr to know which server to add to which group.

One way to help see what the return is would be do print out the `ec2` variable:

`- debug: var=ec2`